# Can't see localstorage event across tabs

Tags: javascript, events, tabs, local-storage

I'm trying to create a simple proof-of-concept regarding the use of localStorage to trigger tabs in my application when changes occur.  I know this is possible based on other articles I've seen.  I understand [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-localstorage-attribute) states the event will fire on ever page **except** the one I'm on - this is in fact what I want. However, I can't seem to get this simple demo to actually work.

I've taken the code below, and opened up multiple tabs of it. Using my Chrome Dev Tools, I can check >localStorage in the console and see the value before and after the "Add" and "Clear" buttons are pressed - they are in fact functioning as desired in storing and clearing the key value pair into local storage, yet the event isn't firing the alert.

I even placed breakpoints in the javascript in my Chrome Dev Tools of each tab, yet I can never seem to get the "onStorageEvent" function to hit in any tab opened.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tab1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="add" onclick="localStorage.setItem('tab','changed')">Add</button>
  <button id="clear" onclick="localStorage.clear()">Clear</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onStorageEvent() {
      alert("storage event: " + localStorage.getItem("tab"));
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageEvent, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to Dekel for pointing out the web-server necessity.  Once I added it to my webserver, things started behaving as desired!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the `window.addEventListener` to work on `storage`:

1. you **MUST** access the page using web-server (`http://a.b.c.d/` or `http://domain`)

   - Direct access (using `file:///` or `c:\file.html` will **not** work.
     (chrome and ie ignore it, firefox and safari can run it anyway).
2. I would consider also removing the 3rd, it is not relevant to elements in your `DOM` tree, and it might cause troubles (let the browser have it's defaults).

This code was tested in Chrome 52, Firefox 47+48, IE 11, Safari 5.7.1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tab1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="add" onclick="localStorage.setItem('tab','changed')">Add</button>
  <button id="clear" onclick="localStorage.clear()">Clear</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onStorageEvent() {
      alert("storage event: " + localStorage.getItem("tab"));
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageEvent);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue.  The 'false' useCapture parameter was included for backwards compatibility with older browsers, as this was once a required field.  Removing it does not change the results. This unchanged result is somewhat expected since - [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - "if not specified, useCapture defaults to false."

Comment: Which browser/os you use?

Comment: Chrome 52.0.x and IE 11.0.9600.x on Win7.

Have you generated working results elsewhere?

Comment: Works in Chrome 52.0.x, Firefox 47, IE 11, Safari 5.1.7.

Comment: One important thing - Chrome and IE **will not** if you run this without a webserver (ie `file:///` or `C:\...` in IE). You **MUST** use a web server for that (`http://127.0.0.1/file.html`)

Comment: YES! That's it!  Thank you!  I hadn't added it to IIS, so I the URL was in fact the file location.  Added to IIS and it's behaving as desired!  
Please add this as a separate answer, and I'll mark it as being correct.  Thank you once again :)