# how to pass alert value to multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, tabs, local-storage

I need to pass the id value as player to all the tabs that are opened by the user i had used the concept of local storage what happens with my code is when i am in that tab i am  getting id as player and this alert should get passed to all the tabs that are opened by the user and the tabs are opened by the user dynamically.I am new to the concept of local storage can anyone help me out

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function onStorageEvent() {
        alert("storage event: " + localStorage.getItem("tab"));
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageEvent, false);
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962045/cant-see-localstorage-event-across-tabs/38962941#38962941 it might help you

Comment: but that happens on button click instead i should do it without any click events that when user just opens a new tab i should pass the id from that tab to all the newly opened tabs without any click events

Comment: so you can use the `window.onload` event (or use [jquery ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/))