# Listen to localstorage change event

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, local-storage

Is there a way to add a change event listener to browser localstorage items.

I have a standalone app that makes changes to localstorage to which I want my backbone view to listen to and accordingly perform some actions.

I couldn't find anything on the internet except for a way to do it in jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
    console.log(e.originalEvent.key, e.originalEvent.newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery can bind to the `storage` event (in the exact way you wrote), however there are a few things you must note:

1. You must run the code behind a real ip/domain (you can read more [my explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962045/cant-see-localstorage-event-across-tabs/38962941#38962941))
2. The `storage` event will fire on every open tab **except** the current tab (which mean - if you have only 1 open tab, and you make some change to the local-storage in that tab - the even **will not** fire). [More information here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-event).

Regarding backbone - try something like this:

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function() {
        $(window).on("storage", this.handleLocalStorageChange)
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But can it be done from backbone?